# Error loading jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this code, a modal will open and ask login information:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Login</a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login Area Riservata</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:Label runat="server">Username</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="username" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="SingleLine" Placeholder="Inserisci nome utente"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label runat="server">Password</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="password" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Password" Placeholder="Inserisci password"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Login" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Login" OnClientClick="Login" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In the Login button i setup the event OnClientClick to a jQuery function:

```
$("[id*=Login]").click(function () {
var user = {
    username: $("[id=username]").val(),
    password: $("[id=password]").val()
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: user,
    url: "data_db.asmx/getdatalogindb",
    contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    success: OnSuccessLogin,
    failure: function (response) {
        alert("failure: " + response.d);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("error: " + response.d);
    }
  });
});

function OnSuccessLogin(response) {
    var result = response.d;
    if (result = true) {
        //redirect to a page
    } else {
        //set visible = true 2 label for visual error
    }
}
```

Problem 1: when i press Login, PostBack start and i can't stop it: I'd like to do all the event on client side: if login param is corret, redirect to a page, if wrong change a css visible to 2 label and retry the login.
Problem 2: The event doesn't start, sometimes warm me that Login is not a function.
How to resolve this 2 problem? Thanks

Comment: P1. https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/  P2. Since you are using jQuery to bind event handlers remove `OnClientClick="Login" `

Comment: Satpal is right, besides of this use $("#Login") instead of the attribute syntax.
To consider: Is using ajax to authenticate users without even hashing the creds the right way? I doubt it.

Comment: `Login is not a function` do you mean `OnSuccessLogin()`?

Comment: Solve with the help of Satpal. Thanks a lot!